# Can I disable the . in an <ol>?

Tags: css, html-lists

I was delighted to learn that CSS lets me say `list-style-type: cjk-ideographic` and get my ordered lists numbered 一, 二, 三, 四.  Unfortunately, it displays like "一." (2 characters: kanji/hanzi 1, then ASCII period).

I looked around and found that the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#algorithmic) actually says to do this:

> The suffix for the cjk-ideographic numbering systems is a dot . U+002E.

(This seems bizarre, since Japanese doesn't even use U+002E for ending sentences.  All of the text I have here uses `、` U+3001 after the number.)

Is there a way to get the automatic "cjk-ideographic" numbering, but have it omit this suffix character, or (better yet) tell it to use U+3001 as the suffix character?

Comment: There's an annotation at the left that reads "Is there a better suffix to use?" - maybe you should ping the W3C guys and let them know. Remember that the CSS3 spec is still in draft :)

Comment: BoltClock: Whoa, I've been poring over that document for a while and I never noticed that!  Good find -- maybe I will.

Comment: In looking for how to give feedback on the "CSS3 Lists" doc, I found this -- http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2009Feb/0252.html -- where someone suggests that "the suffix should be changed to none".  This email is linked to from their wiki as "Issue 2" with lists, so I guess they know already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you only want the numbering but not the dot. If that's the case, you can do

```
ol {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;  
    counter-reset: item;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(item, cjk-ideographic) " ";
    counter-increment: item;    
}
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/82SSG/1/

Comment: That doesn't appear to retain the required, and explicitly-chosen, `list-style-type` of `cjk-ideographic`. May I offer you a refinement of your [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/82SSG/1/)?

Comment: This will remove the dot after the numbers.

Comment: @David Thomas: You can pass it to the `counter()` function: `counter(item, cjk-ideographic)` In this case, he totally glossed over the `list-style-type`, as evident in the fallback `list-style`.

Comment: But your original demo *loses* the `list-style-type` that he chose deliberately, and for which the period (dot) is inappropriate. The refinement, in my previous comment, achieves both.

Comment: @BoltClock, yeah, I know (see the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/82SSG/1/) I posted in my comment...which, admittedly, wasn't yet there when I left the comment. =)

Comment: @Hussein, yes. My point isn't what comes *after* the item, it's that the *item itself* was in the wrong type/style/format; it was `decimal` instead of `cjk-ideographic`...

Comment: I edited your answer to include `counter(item, cjk-ideographic)`. Without it, the question is not really being answered.

Comment: @thirtydot: You saved him from a likely potential downvote. I thank you on his behalf :)

Comment: @thirtydot, yeah. I've been sat hoping that no-one down-voted him (because I'd've felt guilty about it, despite it not being me), and that he'd update the posted code. So, thanks from me, too... =)